# Display Texture in WebGL

Tags: webgl, shader, textures

I'm having some issues to get my thoughts and results straight.
First of all I'm able to create a Texture with a given size.
I attach it to a Framebuffer and write stuff into this texture. WebGL Inspector extension in Chrome clearly shows that.

But currently I'm stuck getting this texture displayed -.-
I know that I need a Shader. But do I need Vertices...? Is there a possibility to just display the texture?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need vertices. All post-processing effects use simple quad mesh to apply effects over it.

For displaying texture you would need to create quad and map framebuffer's texture (color attachment) on it.

Hope this helps and don't be too nervous about waiting for the answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I just needed some push in the right direction.
I created a full screen quad out of two triangles and added some texturecoords and finally bound my texture to it :)